# AngulerJSのモジュールエラー

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngulerJS（1.5.8）を使ってAJAX通信を行うのですが
contorollerの定義のスクリプトでモジュールエラーが発生しています。

```
[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A93)%0A%20%20%20at%20b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A123)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A378)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A469)%0A%20%20%20at%20q%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A353)%0A%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A319)%0A%20%20%20at%20cb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A330)%0A%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A388)%0A%20%20%20at%20Bc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A172)%0A%20%20%20at%20fe%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FVESales%2Fresources%2Fjs%2Fcomm%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A1
```

対応方法がお分かりの方がいればご教授お願いします
html（jspです）
と
javascriptは以下の通りです。

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- <html lang="ja" ng-app="app" ng-hint> -->
<html lang="ja" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
     <title>ユーザー会社登録</title>

    <!-- ファビコン -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<c:url value="/resources/images/vikingegg.ico" />">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/comm/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- 全画面共通スタイル -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/comm/projectcomm/common.css" />" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/comm/jquery/jquery.min.js" />" ></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/comm/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" />" ></script>


    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/comm/angular/angular.min.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/comm/angular/angular.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- AngulerJS Debug hint.js -->
    <!-- <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/comm/angular/hint.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

    <!-- ユーザー会社登録画面のスタイル -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/UserCampany.css" />" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- ユーザー会社登録画面のスクリプト -->
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/UserCampany.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body  ng-controller="controller">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="FormUserCampany" method="POST" action="UserCampany">

        <div class="center-block">
            <div class="row profile-img">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <ul id="profile-img"><img src="<c:url value="${systemImage}"/>" alt=""></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-left">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                    <font><b>${systemName}</b></font>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-left">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                    <font>${DspUserMode}&nbsp; : ${DspUserName}</font>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">

                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="${logoutButton}">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" align="center">
                    <font size="3" > <b>ユーザー会社情報登録</b></font>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p style="border-top:groove 4px #cccccc;width:90%;align:center;"></p>
            </div>


            <!-- 入力内容  -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputCampanyName">会社名</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputCampanyName"  placeholder="会社名" size="15" maxlength="30" value="${InpSystemName}" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputCampanyKanaName">会社カナ名</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputCampanyKana"  placeholder="会社カナ名" size="15" maxlength="30" value="${InpSystemName}" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputOrganization">組　織</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

                    <select name="select_organization" class="form-control" >
                        ${inputOrganization}
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputAddress">住　所</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputYubin">郵便番号</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputYubin1"  size="3" maxlength="3" value="${InputYubin1}" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputYubin2"  size="4" maxlength="4" value="${InputYubin2}" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <input class="btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" params="update" name="submitbtn" value="${yubinButton}">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputTodofuken">都道府県</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

                    <select name="select_todofuken" class="form-control" ng-model="ngTodofuken">
                        ${inputTodofuken}
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputShikuchoson">市区町村</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

                    <select name="select_shikuchoson" class="form-control"  ng-focus="shFocus()" ng-model="shikuchosonDeff"  ng-options="menu as menu.label for menu in shikuchosonList">
                        ${inputShikuchoson}
                    </select>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputBanchi">番　地</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputBanchi"  size="20" maxlength="80" value="${inputBanchi}" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                &nbsp;
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" for="InputSystemName">ビル/建物名</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputBillding"  size="20" maxlength="80" value="" >
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                <input class="btn btn-default  btn-lg" type="submit" params="cancel" name="submitbtn" value="${cancelButton}">
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input class="btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" params="update" name="submitbtn" value="${updateButton}">
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input class="btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" params="new" name="submitbtn" value="${newButton}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

スクリプト
// JavaScript Document


//ApplicationInitModules
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//ApplicationController
ここでエラー>>app.controller("controller", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)
{

    //住所（市区町村プルダウン）

    $scope.shikuchosonList = [];
        $http(
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "./get_Shikuchoson",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                        //UpdateBindingSource
                        $scope.supplierClassList = data.supplierClassList;
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                        alert('データ取得失敗（市区町村）');
                })


    $scope.shikuchosonDeff = null;

    $scope.shFocus = function(){
        $http(
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "./get_Shikuchoson",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                        //UpdateBindingSource
                        $scope.supplierClassList = data.supplierClassList;
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
                {
                        alert('データ取得失敗（市区町村）');
                })



    }


}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

「angular.min.js」と「angular.js」を指定していますが、調査したところAngular1.2以上のバージョンの場合に「angular.js」だけの指定にすべきとの記載があるサイトがあり、実施したところ、Exceptionがはっきりし,エラーが解明できました。